# How to create custom header options for each screen multi stack navigation react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am looking for a way to set custom header options (styling, icons, enabling/disabling back button, left and right options for the header) for each of the screen in the stacks, while maintaining multi-stack architecture for my app in react native?
This is how my App.js looks right now, and I am willing to change it if need be.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const { getInitialState } = useLinking(ref, {
    prefixes: ['FoodApp://'],
  });

  const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

  function AuthStackScreen() {
    return (
      <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogIn} />
        <AuthStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
      </AuthStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

  //I'd like to set different header options for each of the screen here
  function AppStackScreen() {
    return (
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen name="MenuCategoryItems" component={MenuCategoryItems} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="Delivery" component={Delivery} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="Account" component={Account} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="Notification" component={Notification} />
        <AppStack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  //TODO: pass customized bar components
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  //I'd like to set different header options for each of the screen here
  function Tabs(){
      return (
          <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <BottomMenu {...props} />}>
              <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Delivery" component={Delivery} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={Account} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Notification" component={Notification} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
      );
  }

  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} />
              <Stack.Screen name="AppStack" component={AppStackScreen} />
              /*Should I place something else here so that I have access to both AppStack and Tabs navigations?*/
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you need but here is how I customize some "borderColor" value for my header component.

You can pass any options you want via the `setOptions` method of the `navigation` component. It will be populated in the `scene.descriptor.options` parameter.

Below an example of how I am using it in my app.

the `header` options for my screen/navigator.

```
header: ({scene, previous, navigation}) => {
        const {options} = scene.descriptor;

        let borderColor = options.borderColor ?? 'yellow';

        if (scene.route.name.startsWith('Test')) {
             borderColor = 'blue';
        }

        return <HeaderBar options={options}
                          title={title}
                          previous={true}
                          navigation={navigation}
                          borderColor={borderColor}
        />;
    }
```

And in any of the screens components I can use

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        borderColor: 'orange'
    })
}, [ navigation ])
```

Now, my `<HeaderBar>` component will receive a prop `borderColor` whose value is 'orange'.

```
export const HeaderBar = ({ options, title, previous, navigation, borderColor = 'yellow' }) => {
    [...]
    console.log(borderColor); // orange
}
```

As you can see, my `HeaderBar` component also receive the full options as a prop, therefore  I could skip the `borderColor` prop and check the options inside the header component itself.

Like so

```
export const HeaderBar = ({ options, title, previous, navigation }) => {
    const { borderColor } = options;
    [...]
}
```

Hope it will help you if not too late.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You could hide header default of react-navigation in your stack.

```
function AppStackScreen() {
return (
  <AppStack.Navigator headerMode={'none'}>
    <AppStack.Screen name="MenuCategoryItems" component={MenuCategoryItems} />
    <AppStack.Screen name="Delivery" component={Delivery} />
    <AppStack.Screen name="Account" component={Account} />
    <AppStack.Screen name="Notification" component={Notification} />
    <AppStack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
  </AppStack.Navigator>
```

Then, you could custom header component and import it in each your screen.
Sorry because my EL. hope help U.

Comment: This does not really help since having a separate header is always an option. I'd like to achieve this by react navigator itself